# Apache - mod_rewrite RewriteRule question

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a few problems with my mod_rewrite rules. There a three different url pattern I want to handle.

1. http://example.com/%module%/%view%-%args%.html
2. http://example.com/%module%/%view%.html
3. http://example.com/%module%

<strike>The following mod_rewrite rules don't really work</strike>. Also I've the problem that the query (example: user.html?foo=bar) doesn't have an effect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_-]*)/?([0-9A-Za-z_]+)-?([0-9A-Za-z_,]*)\.html$ index.php?__module=$1&__view=$2&__argv=$3

    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_-]*)/?$ index.php?__module=$1&__view=&__argv=
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the query string, flag your rules with QSA (Query String Append).

What you are trying to configure is called a "front controller", of which there are already quite a lot ready-made. Maybe you should have a look at some popular PHP frameworks and adopt one that suits you.

Comment: I'm working on a PHP5 framework, because I like programming and the aspect of learning by doing. If you are interested: http://code.google.com/p/quail/. I want to keep it simple.